# how to start name node in cdh 5.5.0 version?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, namenode

I started the Cloudera manager successfully but while trying to see the list of files it throws error related to  namenode. After that I checked the namenode is started or not , but it says

> Unable to connect
>       Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at quickstart.cloudera:50070.
>       The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
>       If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection.    If your computer or network is protected by a firewall
>   or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Can you post `jps` response